# if statement with is_active_sidebar()

Tags: php, theme-development, sidebar

I found a code in my sidebar-content-bottom.php in the theme itself that I don't really understand.

```
if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) && ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ) ) {
return;}
```

I know that both conditions must be true that the if function activates

```
return;
```

But what does it return then? Two times true on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't return anything, it just jumps back out of the function.

That's basically "If this is neither `sidebar-2` nor `sidebar-3`, don't continue in this function".

Comment: So is my assumption right that when this code exists in my php file:

    <?php   if ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) && ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ) ) {
 return;}

?> 
<aside>....</aside>

That the html function after the if function "<aside>"is uneffected and I could just delete the if statement because it just does nothing?!

Comment: No, or rather: not necessarily. As long as either of those two sidebars are active (that is: contain widgets), the function will execute as if those lines weren't there at all. If both sidebars are inactive, however, the code following that condition will not execute.

Comment: @Martin It sounds like your theme is not outputting the aside element if neither sidebar 2 or 3 has widgets in it.

Comment: It doesn't affect anything on my page when I delete the if function. That's why I was wondering about the function and what it does. In both cases everything worked fine. My question is therefore answered. Thanks guys!!!

Comment: Probably because you have widgets in sidebars 2 & 3. If you remove them it will behave differently. It's not doing nothing